# Parsing a KML from a url using the GMUKMLParser Google Maps iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a kml file online and have the url for it. I'm using the Google Maps iOS SDK and have got a map loading a local kml file fine using the GMUKMLParser like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"KML_Sample" ofType:@"kml"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
GMUKMLParser *parser = [[GMUKMLParser alloc] initWithURL:url];
[parser parse];
GMUGeometryRenderer *renderer = [[GMUGeometryRenderer alloc] initWithMap:_mapView
                                                              geometries:parser.placemarks
                                                                  styles:parser.styles];
[renderer render];
```

What I'd like to do is call my kml online rather than a local kml file, I've searched and searched and cant find an answer anywhere!

Comment: `[[GMUKMLParser alloc] initWithURL:url]`, so you can't put an "web url" there?

Comment: What an absolute noob mistake, yes you can!! Doesn't work quite right but it does get the data from the file!

Comment: What do you mean " Doesn't work quite right"? Because it taking long time? Are you familiar with sync/async call? Might want to preload, use async call with `NSURLSession` and do the `initWithData:` instead.